# Help Identify 3-wire SE cable

Tags: electrical, receptacle, 240v, range

[image]

TRIPLE-E ALLOY TYPE SE CABLE STYLE U TYPE XHHW CDRS 600 for electric range

Follow up question:
Is the 3 wire a grounded neutral conductor or an equipment grounding conductor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The bare wire is a neutral

What you have is a Type SE, Style U cable.  These always consist of two insulated wires surrounded by an uninsulated braided metal wrap (like the shield on a data cable, just with fewer strands) and a jacket laid over the wrap.  This means it's eligible for the exception to 250.146 that permits NEMA 10 (3-wire) range and dryer sockets to continue in use, and since this cable is indeed connected to a a NEMA 10 socket, then the "bare wire" (aka the braided metal wrap, twisted together to form a wire) is a grounded neutral, not an equipment grounding conductor.

Comment: Thank you! That's the answer I was looking for and I'm going to mark this question as solved.
Follow up question (and do let me know if I should a new thread)
Would it be possible to add # **10** AWG GROUND from another branch (hot-water heater) in order to retrofit ground and replace this receptacle with a 4-wire one to be able to use it for an induction range that came with a 4-wire (2x**6**AWG + 2x**8**AWG) plug?

Comment: This is on a 50A breaker so both Hot must be 6AWG correct?

Comment: @Matt -- SE can be run at 75degC so an 8-8-8 cable suffices for 50A

Comment: are you implying that this could be a 6AWG or possibly 8AWG? do we know for sure? Not sure how to check the gauge of a stranded wire

Comment: I started a new thread with those new questions https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/248564/is-it-possible-to-add-a-retorfit-ground-wire-to-a-3-wire-type-se-style-u-cabl